# Как в Python получить название шрифта из файла шрифта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, шрифты, pil

Как в Python получить название шрифта из файла шрифта?

Код:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fnt_filename, 14)
print(fnt.getname())
```

Вывод:

```
('Arial', 'Regular')
```

А требуется (просто):

```
Arial
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from PIL import ImageFont

fnt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 14)

print(fnt.getname()[0])
Arial
```

Comment: Благодарю, получилось!
Можете подсказать, как результат этого `fnt.getname()[0]` положить в текстовую переменную? На такое, например, fnt_name = print(fnt.getname()[0]) print(fnt_name) выдаёт: Arial
None

Comment: @okonik  `fnt_name = fnt.getname()[0]`

Comment: Благодрю, получилось!